# in classic editor, is there a way to add media lib files to the content search when creating a link?

Tags: media-library, links, visual-editor

In TinyMCE Editor, one can highlight some text, hit Ctrl-K and search for a list of matching posts to link to. Is there a way to add Media Lib Attachments into that list of possibilities?